# PHP MYSQL connection to Oracle Cloud server recieving "no route to host"

Tags: php, mysql, linux, networking, mysqli

**EDIT:** official fix i found: (sudo) "iptables -I INPUT -s 0/0 -p tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT" ... no other iptables commands worked but this one did

I have two Linux servers set up. I will refer to Linux server 1 as LS1 and Linux server 2 as LS2.
LS1 is running Linux 5.4.0-125-generic x86_64 and LS2 is running Linux 5.15.0-1018-oracle aarch64.
LS1 is an OVH VPS on the "VPS 2016 SSD 3" lineup running Ubuntu 20.04
LS2 is an Oracle Cloud instance with the shape "VM.Standard.A1.Flex" and the following network subnet(solely for testing, I know this is highly insecure and will be fixed once this problem is sorted out): 
Stateless | Source | IP Protocol | Source Port Range | Destination Port Range | Type and Code |  Allows | Description
Ingress: No | 0.0.0.0/0 | All Protocols | N/A | N/A | N/A | All traffic for all ports | N/A

Egress: No  | 0.0.0.0/0 | All Protocols | N/A | N/A | N/A | All traffic for all ports | N/A

 
LS1 has a MYSQL database set up with the schema called "school". The MySQL username is also "school" and is set up to allow connections from any host("%"). The user that connects to the server is called "school" as well and has been configured to allow connection over username & password. root("ubuntu") connects via SSH key.
LS2 hosts a website via apache2. I am trying to use PHP to connect to the database on LS1 and grab some simple information as a test. the code I am using to test is as follows: 

config.php:

```
$link = new mysqli("*LS1 IP*", "school", "password", "school");
```

^replaced real ip with LS1 IP for security without removing clarity of purpose
the test page contains this code:

```
<?php

//start session
session_start();
require_once "config.php";

$query = "SELECT firstname, lastname FROM user WHERE ID = '00978362'";

if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
        echo $row[0];
        echo $row[1];
    }
}

?>
```

the database has the following entry which is accessed via MYSQL workbench using "ubuntu@LS1Host" SSH Hostname and username + SSH keyfile & "127.0.0.1" "3306" MYSQL host + port and "school" username: 
[screenshot of server connection page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKJv4.png)
[screenshot of data entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4oAx.png)
When i try to load the page that should display the information, i get this error: 
[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ed4hc.png) --> "no route to host"
but when I run nmap port scan of LS1 from LS2 (scan of mysql server from website server) it works fine: 
[screenshot of nmap port scan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZCab.png)

I have tried connecting to LS1 via SSH2 but could not seem to get that to work. Any help would be appreciated. **I am not well versed in this so please try to understand that when replying and rating the post**. I tried to give as much detail as possible, so it may be long, but if there's any info you need that I haven't provided please ask. **Thanks in advance!**

extra possibly helpful info: running mysql -u school -p and then entering password works fine while on LS1, so I think MYSQL is set up fine: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMme1.png

 **HOWEVER**, running **mysql -h LS1Host -u school -p** and then entering password **ON LS2** results in this error: **ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'LS1Host:3306' (113)**, but I couldn't find much helpful info about this error when googling it
This is confusing to me because LS2 can ping LS1 on port 3306 just fine, but when trying to connect to it, it fails, so I assume it is a networking problem, but I am unsure how to fix it.

Comment: Is `LS1 IP` what's actually in your code, or is that dummy data for posting here?

Comment: i am using an actual ip, ex "x.x.x.x" but did not want to post it here, so i changed it to LS1 so it is easy to tell which server is being connected to by which etc

Comment: No route to host usually implies a network routing issue. Are the IP addresses of the two machines in the same subnet?

Do you know how to list the routing table of your machines? If so, can you confirm they have a default route? Does the default route include routing to the other machines’ subnet? Is one of the servers using a private IP (10.anything, 192.168.anything, 172.16-31.anything) while the other machine has a public IP?

Comment: one of their ips is: 149.5x.1x.17x, and the other is 132.14x.16x.14x, so they should both be public. They have no problem communicating via pinging each other. LS2 routing table is: https://i.imgur.com/sGnQfmm.png and LS1 routing table is: https://i.imgur.com/spq1m2N.png @sea0003

Comment: this was solved by using the command "iptables -I INPUT -s 0/0 -p tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT" which is frustrating because i tried like 50 iptable commands and at one point completely disabled iptables and it still didnt work, but magically it worked now.... weird

Answer (score 0):

"iptables -I INPUT -s 0/0 -p tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT" solved the problem. Posted this so i can accept it as solved(in 48 hours)